# Docker failed to build npm script without Error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY src ./
RUN npm  --verbose install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8000
```

Dependencies from **packages.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.2.0",
    "globstar": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
```

Info: `--verbose` was added only for get more debug info.
the problem is localy I'm building everything good, but Docker set me `The command '/bin/sh -c npm  --verbose install' returned a non-zero code`

but `npm install` returns:

```
added 269 packages from 289 contributors and audited 814 packages in 6.227s

15 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 6589ms
npm info ok
The command '/bin/sh -c npm  --verbose install' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container...
```

Extra info 1. Adding `--production` or `--quiet` give this same exception
Extra info 2. I'm running Linux under Windows (WSL)
Extra info 3. Everything is updated, in last version
Extra info 4. Using `sudo` also don't work

Any Ideas?

Comment: Looks like there's a GitHub issue with pretty recent discussion about this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36682 - sounds like a bug!

Answer (score 0):

According to cbr comment - I thought that error code was random - my bad.

WSL have problems with using downloaded binaries in docker (in this case `node-sass`).
This issue at this moment is known and have no workaround.